# How can I divide sibling elements inside new elements based on a sibling value in Xdocument?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have these entry elements:

```
<Entry>
  <pos STYLE="NUM">1</pos >
  <tran></tran>
  <pos  STYLE="NUM">2</pos >
  <example></example>
  <pos  STYLE="NUM">3</pos >
  <elem></elem>
</Entry>
<Entry>
  ...
</Entry>
```

How can I transform the elements in between num elements to new elements so in the end I have this:

```
<Entry>
  <body>
    <tran></tran>
  </body>
  <body>
    <example></example>
  </body>
  <body>
    <elem></elem>
  </body>
</Entry>
```

EDIT:: sofar i load xml document iterate all the elements and do some formatting that is irrelevant to this question

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(sourceDocument,LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
foreach (XElement rootElement in doc.Root.Elements())
{
    foreach (XElement childElement in rootElement.Descendants())
    {
        //add new body if <pos style=num>
        if (childElement.Attribute("STYLE") != null)
        {
            //if next node is NUM
            var nextNode = childElement.XPathSelectElement("following-sibling::*");

            if (nextNode != null)
            if (nextNode.Attribute("STYLE").Value == "NUM")
            {
                newBodyElem = new XElement("body");
            }
}
}
```

Comment: @HeinA.Grønnestad do you need want more detailed code? I think that is the relevant part

Comment: Teemu Eronen there was no code when I commented...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be considered as a grouping problem which restructures the contents of the entry elements:

```
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("input.xml");
        foreach (XElement entry in doc.Descendants("Entry").ToList())
        {
            foreach (var group in entry.Elements().Except(entry.Elements("pos")).GroupBy(child => child.ElementsBeforeSelf("pos").Last()))
            {
                group.Remove();
                group.Key.ReplaceWith(new XElement("body", group));
            }
        }
        doc.Save("output.xml");
```